# google sheet external web app put authentication with key fails

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am writing an external web app against a google sheet. I am using a key for authentication.

My code works well for an "Ajax" get request with the key appended as parameter &key= ...

However, when I try to write to the sheet using an "Ajax" Put, appending the same key as parameter leads to an authentication error.

I don't see in the sheets API administration panel any indication that the key is either read-only or read-write, so I am stuck ... not sure why the same key doesn't work for put.

any thoughts would be much appreciated,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like i found the problem.

It had to do with cross domain requests. After setting the header to allow this, it worked.